# How to output a given column name in a SQL SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I am trying to output a certain column name (out of lots of columns in a given table) in a `SELECT` clause. That way, I don't have to hard-code the column name. Currently, with the hard-code method, I have something like:

```
SELECT
    'name_of_column'
FROM some_table
```

I know how to get a list of all columns via the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but I just need a particular one. How can this be done?

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. `I just need a particular one`. Which one?? If you need particular one you did everything correct, just select that one. Then why to post a question?

Comment: How do you determine the column you want?

Comment: What is your input? You say you are trying to output a certain column name out of lots of columns; what are your criteria for selection?

Comment: Let's say I have 50 columns in my table.  I will already know which column whose name I want to output.  For example, I want to output the name of column 'this_column'.  So, I want my query to return the value this_column.

Comment: If you already know the name of the column, why do you need a query to return it?

Comment: I think I will keep as hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why would you do this if you know the column name just use the column in the query, anyway lets say you have some requirement that you have to do this ,since you have mentioned it is only one column that you need you can do something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData
 @TableName   SYSNAME
,@ColumnName  SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Sql = N' SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
FROM sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE t.name = @TableName
  AND c.name LIKE '%' + @ColumnName + '%'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql 

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for, but here is my attempt:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(50) = 'Test'; --change this to match table name 
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50) = 'ID'; --change this to match column name you need
BEGIN
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName;
END
```